# TypeScript: How to turn an interface of fields w/ nested interfaces into a union of intersection types?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, web, components

I am trying to construct a `Box` component that accepts a variable `is` attribute to determine the element that is rendered:

```html
<Box is="a" href="...">
    ...
</Box>
```

So to support that typing I have an interface of standard elements and their attributes like so:

```js
interface IElements {
    a: {href: string, ...};

    button: {...};

    ...
}
```

Then I created a utility type that generates the appropriate intersection of `{is: TAG, ...attributes[TAG]}`:

```js
type IAttributes<K extends keyof IElements> = {
    is: K;
} & IElements[K];

const attributes: IAttributes<"a"> = {
    is: "a",

    href: "..."
}
```

Since I am creating a `Box` component that renders every standard HTML element I created a union to have its input properties typing change based on the `is` property:

```js
type IProps = IAttributes<"a"> | IAttributes<"button">;
```

Is there a way of having TypeScript iterate through every HTML tag from `IElements` using `IAttributes` rather then me having to type out a union of every single HTML tag?

I consume `IElements` from an external library where there might be new tags added and removed between versions. So I would like to have `IProps` built dynamically in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could make `IProps` a *distributive object type* where you first make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and then immediately [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with the full [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of its keys to produce a union output:

```
type IProps = {
    [K in keyof IElements]: IAttributes<K>
}[keyof IElements]
// type IProps = IAttributes<"a"> | IAttributes<"button"> | ...
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFEA2EC2FwDOyA3gFDIXJwBcJyAFlBDLQWFKAObIC+A3OUoAjAK5gwAexC1iyUeKkBlMCJgtkIETiHReAnqUNgAngAcUqAILiO8iAQA8AaWQQAHpBAATIgGsIxhIwaFi4+GAEAHzIALwkghTABLRO+sgAZCHYeIQA2k4AugKkJuZoAApQEqZEcWSUyPnIoMj+gcEY2eEEBbRWNsB2jk6RpDy5bUFZYYQFpAD088ilFpXVtWjW7INi9g4ARHD70QA+mwNDB-KSIMdAA)